# how to check query in firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Image attached for reference of firestore[image: Cloud Firestore]

trying to check the query in firestore to know if the user has sent the request or received it and it can perform the task accordingly and change the text of button.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("request").whereEqualTo("userid",otherUserid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                List<DocumentSnapshot> document = task.getResult().getDocuments();
                if(document.contains("received")){
                    current_state="req_received";
                    send.setText("Accept Request");
                }else if(document.contains("sent")){
                    current_state = "req_sent";
                    send.setText("Cancel Request");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The following code is to send or cancel the Request and it working fine but when I go back to another activity and come back again then the text of button changes to send request which must have stayed to cancel request as the request has already been sent.

```
 send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (userid.equals(otherUserid)) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Cannot send request to your own", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //--------Not friends.....

            send.setEnabled(false);
            if (current_state.equals("not_friends")) {

                FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                //  String userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                Map<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
                profile.put("userid", otherUserid);

                firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("request")
                        .document("sent").set(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            //  String userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            Map<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
                            profile.put("userid", userid);

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(otherUserid).collection("request")
                                    .document("received").set(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        send.setEnabled(true);
                                        current_state = "req_sent";
                                        send.setText("Cancel Request");

                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Failed sending request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            //-------- Cancel request.......

            if (current_state.equals("req_sent")) {
                FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<>();
                //  String userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                profile.put("userid", FieldValue.delete());

                firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userid).collection("request")
                        .document("sent").update(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            //  String userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<>();
                            profile.put("userid", FieldValue.delete());

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(otherUserid).collection("request")
                                    .document("received").update(profile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        send.setEnabled(true);
                                        current_state = "not_friends";
                                        send.setText("Send Request");

                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Request canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Failed request canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }


        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: This is due to Activity Lifecycle. I suggest you to read the Android Documentation on the same topic and you will get the reason why it is so.

Comment: does that comparison `document.contains("received")` working correctly? not sure that doing contains work on `List<DocumentSnapshot>`.

Comment: Check document ID for "sent", rather than check if it contains a field called "sent".

Comment: @MuthuThavamani, No, it not working. So how I can make it working? What do you suggest? I tried reading documentation but not able to get it.

Comment: @codebod , What changes I need to make? Pls help me out. I even tried.exist, .equal, but no desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed, if the error lies only on the comparison part changing the query iteration like below might fix the issue.

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
               if(document.getId().contains("received")){
                    current_state="req_received";
                    send.setText("Accept Request");
                    // do pending stuffs or break the loop here
                } else if(document.getId().contains("sent")){
                    current_state = "req_sent";
                    send.setText("Cancel Request");
                    // do pending stuffs or break the loop here
                }
     }
}
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: thanks for your reply and help, I tried this code but now it changes the text for every user, so then I further added the code inside it to take the query snapshot of the field and compare it with the userid that whether it exist in "sent". or "received" but is not showing desired result. How can I check that?

Comment: Glad, you did it!